# IIS Server Side Includes do not show on mobile

Tags: html, iis, mobile, server-side-includes

I have IIS 7 and Server Side Includes work fine in all desktop browsers. But when I try on mobile (iPhone or Android) they don't show. Code extract:

```html
<body>
    <!--#include file="Header.cshtml"-->
    <img src="Images/Dublin02.png" class="banner">
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is caused by IIS, but it can work when request come from desktop browser. It is necessary to debug it on mobile so that can be determined whether the image is not successfully requested or the request is successful but the mobile device cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found out it's the file extension. I was using index.cshtml but when I change it to index.shtml it worked.